# combining IE6 and IE7 css hacks in same stylesheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I usually use IE conditionals and have a stylesheet for each. This for me is a much neater way to do this. However due to a certain constraints, I have to hack ie6 and 7 in the same stylesheet.

I know it won't validate, but how do you isolate ie6 and ie7 with hacks in the same stylesheet?

Answer (score 7):

**Comprehensive List of Browser-Specific CSS Hacks**

Source: http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

```
/***** Selector Hacks ******/

/* IE6 and below */
* html #uno  { color: red }

/* IE7 */
*:first-child+html #dos { color: red } 

/* IE7, FF, Saf, Opera  */
html>body #tres { color: red }

/* IE8, FF, Saf, Opera (Everything but IE 6,7) */
html>/**/body #cuatro { color: red }

/* Opera 9.27 and below, safari 2 */
html:first-child #cinco { color: red }

/* Safari 2-3 */
html[xmlns*=""] body:last-child #seis { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:nth-of-type(1) #siete { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:first-of-type #ocho {  color: red }

/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #diez  { color: red  }
}

/* iPhone / mobile webkit */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 #veintiseis { color: red  }
}


/* Safari 2 - 3.1 */
html[xmlns*=""]:root #trece  { color: red  }

/* Safari 2 - 3.1, Opera 9.25 */
*|html[xmlns*=""] #catorce { color: red  }

/* Everything but IE6-8 */
:root *> #quince { color: red  }

/* IE7 */
*+html #dieciocho {  color: red }

/* Firefox only. 1+ */
#veinticuatro,  x:-moz-any-link  { color: red }

/* Firefox 3.0+ */
#veinticinco,  x:-moz-any-link, x:default  { color: red  }



/***** Attribute Hacks ******/

/* IE6 */
#once { _color: blue }

/* IE6, IE7 */
#doce { *color: blue; /* or #color: blue */ }

/* Everything but IE6 */
#diecisiete { color/**/: blue }

/* IE6, IE7, IE8 */
#diecinueve { color: blue\9; }

/* IE7, IE8 */
#veinte { color/*\**/: blue\9; }

/* IE6, IE7 -- acts as an !important */
#veintesiete { color: blue !ie; } /* string after ! can be anything */
```

**Be sure** to check out other solutions like using javascript libraries for that purpose:
I recommend http://www.modernizr.com which is supported by the same author of the above list of hacks Paul Irish. With Modernizr you can do sometihng like:

```
#menu{ .. }
.ie6 #menu{ .. }
.ie7 #menu{ .. }
```

Instead of hacking, much cleaner code, easier to understand.

Also i suggest you check http://www.quirksmode.org/, it has a very complete list of the supported browser features and compatibility.

Comment: Is Modernizr open-source ? Is it safe to use for professional sites ? Also for attribute hacks, what is the syntax ?

Comment: @testndtv If you open the link is the first thing that it says, Modernizar is an "open source library". Yes it is safe for profesional development as it was made for that. Some of the best guys out there worked on it. If you want to know more open the link and go to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this enormous table](http://centricle.com/ref/css/filters/?highlight_columns=true).
It indicates that you can use `*color: green;`.